# Query to find SUM based on week

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like date , sales , region

| date | Sales | Region |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/02/2021 | 20 | 1 |
| 12/02/2021 | 23 | 1 |
| 13/02/2021 | 30 | 2 |
| 14/02/2021 | 50 | 2 |
| 15/02/2021 | 10 | 3 |
| 16/02/2021 | 10 | 3 |

How to extract sum of sales per region  based on weeks (Week starting from  Monday to Sunday)

Comment: Show us how you tried to extract sum of sales per region based on weeks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: I am using sql server

Comment: I've added the <sql-server> tag for you.

Comment: Also show us the expected result. E.g. what happens if you have same week number, but different years?

Comment: Need to enhance it with the from dt and to date , week starting from Monday

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the week before grouping.

This should work for you:

```
SELECT DATEPART(week, date) AS Week,
FROM table
GROUP BY DATEPART(week, RegistrationDate);
```